# Flutter: turn off exception being caught by gesture

Tags: flutter

I would like to have a button, where I can force an ArgumentError for various testing reasons (e.g., how the error page looks like, whether Crashlytics works etc.).

I have set the button up like this:

```
if (kDebugMode)
 MaterialButton(
 onPressed: () {
   throw ArgumentError("ArgumentError: Test via SettingsButton");
 },
 color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
 child: Text('Force ArgumentError', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
),
```

When running the app in debug mode from VS Code both in emulator or on physical device (or standalone), I can click the button. Also, VS Code will pause the debug process, informing me an ArgumentError has occurred as expected.

But, I never see the error screen within the app. Instead, I receive the following debug message:

> ════════ Exception caught by gesture
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> ArgumentError was thrown while handling a gesture: Invalid
> argument(s): ArgumentError: Test via SettingsButton
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      SettingsPage.build. (package:XXX/main.dart:2223:27) main.dart:2223
> #1      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
> ink_well.dart:1183
> #2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
> recognizer.dart:275
> #3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)

The app will continue to run afterwards, if I continue it in VS code by clicking the play icon in VS code.

My questions:

1. Is this a thing that an error resulting from a button onPressed will automatically be caught by gesture (like in a try-catch-clause, I suppose)?
2. How can I prevent this? I need an error with error page to result from the button onPressed!

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ErrorWidget-class.html

In the link above, at least a way is shown how to force an uncaught error from tabbing a button: 
Introduce a global variable bool throwError = false; Set it true by clicking the button. Check whether the variable is true in the build context of the app and throw the Error there.